# Exception thrown when using dequeue method from queue

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, queue, singly-linked-list

I am trying to make my queue library and when I implement the dequeue method, an exception is throw "0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted (parameters: 0x77475910)." This only gets thrown AFTER I already remove an item from the queue, the item is returned successfully however the first element is not removed, here is how I wrote the code :

```
typedef struct {
   int value;
   struct queue_item * next;
} queue_item;
typedef queue_item * queue;
```

and this is the method:

```
int dequeue(queue q)
{
    queue fi = q;
    int value = q->value;
    fi = q;
    q = q->next;
    free(fi);
    return  value;
}
```

Comment: There is a bug somewhere in the code you didn't show. You need to show a [MCVE]. BTW: in C parameters are passed by value, so if you call `xyz = dequeue(somequeue);` then `somequeue` won't be modified. That may be your problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
 int dequeue(queue q)
 {
   queue fi = q;
```

You pass `q` by value so even though you make `q` point to next element inside `dequeue()`, outside `dequeue()`, it is still pointing to freed memory and using `q` will crash.

Pass a pointer to `q` to `dequeue`

Answer (score 1):

For starters this declaration

```
typedef struct {
   int value;
   struct queue_item * next;
} queue_item;
```

is invalid.

It should look like

```
typedef struct queue_item {
   int value;
   struct queue_item * next;
} queue_item;
```

The function `dequeue` deals with a copy of the original queue pointer because it is passed to the function by value.

So this statement in the function

```
q = q->next;
```

does not change the original pointer.

You should pass the pointer by reference. For example

```
int dequeue(queue *q)
{
    queue fi = *q;
    int value = ( *q )->value;

    *q = ( *q )->next;
    free( fi );

    return  value;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I can't believe I didn't remember that, thank you. Why is the first declaration of the struct invalid ?

Comment: @Matthew It declares two different structures. The first one is unnamed and the second one is incomplete. The compiler should issue a diagnostic message at least for this statement q = q->next;

Comment: I understand, thank you !